# Google OAuth's access token's expiry timezone

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

I recently switched to the Google+ Sign in OAuth2 hybrid approach.

When the request code is exchanged for the access token, the expiry time and created time is sent back along with the access token in seconds.

I need to know the sent timezone is. I need this to make comparison with my server's time and be able to deduce if access token has actually expired.

What's the timezone or how do I determine it?

Comment: Its the amount of time left. You can just be able to add it to now.

Comment: @DalmTo you did not understand the problem. i can do a simple arithmetic of comparing `expires_in + created` with `expires_in + time()`. The `created` field is a time field in a specific time zone. `time()` gives current time on my server. I initially thought `created` was sent form Google. In that case, i would have needed to know their time zone for my comparison to be valid. Understood?

Answer (score 2):

The token bundle sent back does not include an actual expiration time, but it does contain the number of seconds for the expected life of the token. If a time is being attached to it, it is being attached by the local library.

That said - you can't necessarily trust this number. There are a number of reasons why the token may have been revoked or is treated as no longer valid. So while you can use it as an estimate of when you'll need to get a new one - you should also handle the case where you use a token and you get an authentication error, forcing you to refresh the token and try again.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

I just went through the Google PHP APi client library. Only to realize the created field was set within the library (on my server) in `Google_Auth_OAuth2`'s authenticate method.

So it is safe to use `$client->isAccessTokenExpired()` instead to try to do one's computation. Works with local time (I guess :))

Thank you.